# Is cleaner way to implement boolean logic that passes if either of two things happen?

Tags: c#, optimization, logic

This happens to me every once in a while and I always end up solving it the same way and then wishing for a cleaner way.

I start out with a calls to related utility functions, followed by and update call.

```
SynchA();
SynchB();
UpdateLastTime();
```

Then later I add check boxes so I have:

```
if(synchA.Checked)
{
  SynchA();
}
if(synchB.Checked)
{
  SynchB();
}
```

BUT now I only want to call UpdateLastTime() of ONE OR BOTH the two executed so invariably I end up with:

```
bool synchHappened = false;
if(synchA.Checked)
{
  SynchA();
  synchHappened = true;
}
if(synchB.Checked)
{
  SynchB();
  synchHappened = true;
}
if(synchHappened)
{
  UpdateLastTime();
}
```

That final step always bothers me because I'm spreading this one bool around to three branches of logic.

Is there some obvious better approach to the above logic/scenario that I could use?

Comment: What about using `if (synchA.Checked || synchB.Checked)` for your last condition?

Comment: That looks reasonably clean to me.

Comment: @adrianbanks, good point - its the over-optimizer in me not wanting to call property accessors twice, but it wouldn't hurt me here.

Comment: @adrianbanks +1 to you, that's how I would do it.

Comment: I don't think that keeps the original workflow tho does it?

Comment: In your case, you don't need the synchHappened variable, as you can use the Checked variables to determine if either ran.  But it still requires 3 if statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main goal would be - **each time as logic has changed - code should be affected at least as possible.** 
So you've to structure such things once and then it will work for you.

In your particular case I would suggest to [Keep It Simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) (no [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), and so on), so
extract and encapsulate a logic of switches into the properties. So each time as requirements will be changed - you've to update either logic of particular switch or main logic itself.

**Switches with encapsulated rules:**

```
bool IsUpdateLastTime
{
 get
 {
    // logic here even can be fully or partially injected 
    // as Func<bool>
    return this.IsSyncA || this.IsSyncB;
 }
}

bool IsSyncA { get { return synchA.Checked; } }
bool IsSyncB { get { return synchB.Checked; } }
```

**Main logic:**

```
if (this.IsUpdateLastTime)
{
  this.UpdateLastTime();
}
```

Comment: How is this any better? It seems like it just moved local logic externally... +1 for the different approach though (and because I'm on a roll :-/)

Comment: @silev - I don't think this code does what the original code does.  In particular, you're not actually calling SynchA or SynchB, and the || operator will short-circuit and possibly not call both Synch's if you were to add it.

Comment: @Mystere Man: absolutely, this is an example of how-to encapsulate logic so main method flow would not be changed each time as logic of each particular case changes

Comment: @pst: "just moved logic externall".. this is enough to decouple many things, such simple trick doing code base more clean and easy to maintain

Comment: @silev - No, your logic does not do what the poster needs it to do.  I don't now why he accepted your answer, your code is not doing what he needs.

Comment: i *think* it's doing what I want - i apologize if i caused confusion accepting this - i.e. instead of adding a local bool i switch to encapsulating the boolean logic at the level of the form instance... this appealed to me as having less additional complexity than my posted code (especially in context of my actual code which is about 100 lines)

Answer (score 2):

This kind of problem is where [Rx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609) is really useful, as you can combine several events into a single one. It can be done with something like this.

(Assuming winforms for this example, but it's similar with WPF etc, just by changing the event names/generic type arg for FromEvent.)

```
var synchAchecked = Observable.FromEvent<EventArgs>(synchA.CheckedChanged);
var synchBchecked = Observable.FromEvent<EventArgs>(synchB.CheckedChanged);
var merged = Observable.Merge(synchAchecked, synchBchecked);

synchAchecked.Subscribe(x => SynchA());
synchBchecked.Subscribe(x => SynchB());
merged.Subscribe(x => UpdateLastTime());
```

Answer (score 2):

One might consider this pattern more compact (and possibly readable) although it still requires the separate variable.

```
bool syncHappened = false;
if(syncHappened |= synchA.Checked) SynchA();
if(syncHappened |= synchB.Checked) SynchB();
if(syncHappened) UpdateLastTime();
```

Comment: I misspelled the last `syncHappened` -- it's fixed now, and compiles.

Comment: Ick. I avoid side-effects in comparison expressions (the "while idiom" for reading streams is about the only one I let slide). However, +1 because "it does work", even if I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: that's an interesting one i never would have come up with

Comment: I don't think this works.  A is checked, B is not.  Unless I'm missing something (I never use such assignments in comparisons so I could be wrong) synchHappened |= SynchB.checked is true and thus SynchB() runs even though it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Some may not like this, but I find it very useful and clean.  It's a bit odd, so the decision to use this is up to you.

```
UpdateLastTime(Either(SynchA(synchA.Checked), SynchB(synchB.Checked)));

private bool Either(bool first, bool second)
{
    return first || second;
}
```

This requires that `SynchA()`, `SynchB()` and `UpdateLastTime()` be modified to do no work if shouldRun is false, and return true or false depending whether the synch occurred.

Answer (score 0):

A bit C centric, but:

```
if (checked_syncs & SYNC_A)
    SyncA();
if (checked_syncs & SYNC_B)
    SyncB();
if (checked_syncs)
    UpdateLastTime();
```

This has the advantage that the last check doesn't have to change (unless you run out of bits, in which case you can switch to a larger primitive type, or just use more than one).  It also has the advantage of effectively doing all the ORs for UpdateLastTime() in parallel, so it is also a fast solution.

NOTE: Of course SYNC_A and SYNC_B have to be unique powers of two, and yes - this may break your encapsulation a bit, and assumes you can |= the condition when the check occurs (may not be possible, or beneficial over setting a boolean if you are talking about a specific GUI toolkit).